# What's the correct way to dispatch/forward events across nested in components in Svelte?

Tags: javascript, events, svelte

I'm curious, what's the best way to forward or dispatch events across multiple levels in component tree in Svelte JS?

Say I have App.Svelte, some intermediate number levels, each containing a child component, and Modal.Svelte. If I want to forward or dispatch an event from Modal to App, what's the right way to do this?

As I understand it, event forwarding in Svelte will traverse up the component tree and forward the event to the first parent that references the forwarded event. (Is this the correct interpretation?)

And using event dispatch approach, each nested component would need to 1/ import createEventDispatcher, 2/ create a dispatcher variable, 3/ define a function, which dispatches the event. Then parent's would need to import the function and reference it inside a tag, such as `<p>`. (Is this correct?)

If I'm correct on both of the above, I'm wondering if there isn't a more streamlined approach, eg connecting the event to stores, which would effectively flatten the component tree such that any component could receive the forwarded event. Though I imagine that this could induce some hard to debug behavior if multiple components reference the same forwarded event.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To forward a event from a child component or DOM element to the parent, you just have to define an `on:event` without handler. E.g.

```html
<button on:click >
<Component on:open >
```

No need to use `createEventDispatcher` just for forwarding.

If you want to share events more widely, you can create an [`EventTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget) and send events through that. Since subscriptions would not happen in the template via `on:event`, you have to make sure to remove listeners again. You can also use a [context](https://svelte.dev/docs#run-time-svelte-setcontext) to just expose the object to a sub-tree of the component hierarchy.

Alternatively, events can be dispatched directly to DOM elements, such events will bubble up the entire element hierarchy (if enabled in the event options).

```js
someElement.dispatchEvent(
  new CustomEvent('my-event', { bubbles: true })
);
```

If you dispatch events to the `window`, directly or via bubbling, you can subscribe to those more conveniently using `svelte:window`:

```html
<svelte:window on:my-event={() => ...} />
```

(These handlers are removed automatically when the component is destroyed.)

Comment: Can you shed some light on EventTarget, subscriptions and listeners? (And so using context would be an alternative to the former, right?)

Comment: The distinction would be between exporting an `EventTarget` instance from a file or setting it as context. An exported instance can be imported anywhere, it would be a singleton. All DOM elements are EventTargets, there is nothing special about creating one separately and using it to send/receive events. See the linked documentation for the relevant functions.

Comment: [Here](https://svelte.dev/repl/2ecafb9a343948f59f764d281b2e6719?version=3.55.1) is an example for the global export/import approach. If subscriptions always happen on component initialization, code for adding/removing subscriptions could be extracted to make everything more concise.

Answer (score 3):

You might consider instead using accessor functions.  In App.svelte, define a function that manipulates your top-level variables. Then place that function in an accessor object and pass that down as a prop to all your components that may need it.

```
<script>
[App.svelte]

let myVar, myObj, myWhatever

function updateMyVal(newValue) {
  myVar = newValue
}

function mergeMyObject(mergeObj) {
  myObj = {...myObj, ...mergeObj}
}

let accessorObject = {
  updateMyVal: updateMyVal,
  mergeMyObject: mergeMyObject
}

</script>

<ChildComponent {accessorObject} {myVar} {myObj} />



. . .
[ChildComponent.svelte]
<script>
  export let accessorObject, myVar, myObj

  accessorObject.updateMyVal(1234)

  accessorObject.mergeMyObject({newProp: newVal})
</script>
```

And so forth... this has the advantage of pushing changes to application-wide variables from the top down, which I've found to work better for complex SPAs than a web of events, two-way-bindings or stores, at least in my limited experience.

Comment: Oh this is a really clever design pattern!

Comment: Is this the same as Prop drilling in React?  The problem being if you want to pass it down several layers of the tree you need to put the `accessorObject` in every component prop list.

Comment: I don't know React, but yes, it does require you to add the accessor object to the prop list of every downstream that might need it. While that adds a few characters of boilerplate I haven't yet found a better way to maintain a sane reaction sequence in a complex SPA. It permits two-way (read/write, up/down) communication vertically through the stack, unlike events which are only up, or two-way bindings that get overly complex very quickly when nesting layers, or stores which don't impose any order on reaction flow. I'm always open for better ideas, but this model has been working well for me.

Comment: Yes, this is one of the primary ways to make React components talk to parents, however the main problem is that if you have a deep chain of nested components the prop you're trying to pass from the top down to the bottom obviously affects every component in-between creating a load of unnecessary dependencies.  I believe context may solve this, but I've not really tried it yet.  I'm currently experimenting with stores which seem similar to a pub/sub system I once wrote to solve this problem.  I've also used (non-svelte) events to communicate over long component distances.

Comment: Absolutely. To balance I restrict the use of top-to-bottom communication to only the absolutely necessary and infrequently updated. Most component communication should be between a parent and an immediate child and there's no need to pass that from the top to all and sundry. Only things that are truly global (or nearly so) in consumption. I've only briefly glanced at context but at first glance it looks somewhat complicated. It's not the first time it's been suggested.